# Console.log fires in if statement but the rest of the code does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I am trying to hide the `$("#shop-subcategories-menu")` when the #filter input has something (text) in it, and toggle it back visible when is empty.
I cannot understand why the `console.log(true)` fires and returns true but the 
`$("#shop-subcategories-menu").toggle(true);` does not fire.

If I write `$("#shop-subcategories-menu").toggle(true);` directly into the console the div toggles back to being visible.

I am obviously missing something but I can't see what please help.

**Long story short: how to make the `<div id="shop-subcategories-menu">TEST</div>` toggle visible when the `<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Search..">` is empty??**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('keyup', '#filter', function (e) {
            if ($(this).val() === '') {
                console.log(true);
                $("#shop-subcategories-menu").toggle(true);
            }
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
                $("#shop-subcategories-menu").toggle(false);
            });
        });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="shop-subcategories-menu">TEST</div>
<p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>  
<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<br><br>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anja</td>
    <td>Ravendale</td>
    <td>a_r@test.com</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure you want `$("#myTable tr").filter` there - maybe `$("#myTable tr").each`, cause that's how you're using it, so the `$("#shop-subcategories-menu").toggle(false)` gets fired for every row.

Comment: Please elaborate, the function is from : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_filters.asp

Comment: Yeah - the way they've used it is rubbish.  Sorry, but w3schools is not a good place to learn jquery.  They've also used it as `each`.  It should be used to filter the results - and then *apply an action on the filtered results*, eg `$("tr").filter(function() { return $(this).text() == "x"; }).show();`

Comment: Either way, the `$("#shop-subcategories-menu").toggle(false)` is still fired for every iteration.  Are you trying to stop the menu from being hidden if there are matching rows?

Comment: I want the menu to be hidden when there is any text in the input and be visible when the input is empty. Can you please post some example some piece of code something? I can't figure this out. In my code everything works but the part where the input is empty and the menu should become visible again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break this down to a much simpler case without the table and the filtering. The table and the filtering are distractions to what you are asking

You can create a simple boolean based on current value and pass that to `toggle()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('keyup', '#filter', function(e) {
    var showMenu = !$(this).val()
    $("#shop-subcategories-menu").toggle(showMenu);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="shop-subcategories-menu">TEST</div>

<p>Type something in the input field to search the table for first names, last names or emails:</p>

<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
```

Comment: Yeah it works but I cannot integrate it with the rest of the code. Can you please integrate it with the table filter?

Comment: Integrate to do what? All you asked was how to handle the search field being empty or not

Comment: Yes but in the context of filtering the table. If you take it out of context it might work but I cannot make it work inside the entire function. If you can find the mistake why would you strip down the function instead of showing where I did wrong?

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work when table and filtering are put back in. The 2 operations have nothing to do with each other beyond using the same input value

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to enter true because `toggle()` does exactly the oposite of the current element state.

(if it's shown it hides it, if it's hidden it shows it)

or:

Just use `hide()` and `show()` of jQuery
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

to have full control

## update to answer.

you will still need to handle what happens when it's not empty

in your function do something like:

```
if ($(this).val() === '') {
  console.log(true);
  $("#shop-subcategories-menu").hide();
} else {
  $("#shop-subcategories-menu").show();
}
```

Comment: My example does not work neither with toggle() (without true) neither with show(). Can you please post an example or some code?

Comment: @Victordb i've edited my answer for a possible solution